# How can I change math font with \setmathfont inside a group?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Consider the following test file and compile it with LuaTeX (TeXLive 2016):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style = TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-regular,
  BoldFont = *-bold,
  ItalicFont = *-italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
  ]

\setsansfont{texgyreadventor}[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-regular,
  BoldFont = *-bold,
  ItalicFont = *-italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
  ]

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{texgyreadventor-regular}
\setmathfont[range=it/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{texgyreadventor-italic}
\setmathfont[range = {}]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

% {
%   \setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{texgyreadventor-regular}
%   \setmathfont[range=it/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{texgyreadventor-italic}
%   \setmathfont[range = {}]{Latin Modern Math}

%   \begin{equation}
%     \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
%   \end{equation}
% }

\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the last lines, LuaTeX hangs forever. How can I change math font inside a group?

---

**EDIT**

I'm well aware that I should not use a non math font to do math but, unfortunately, a sans serif math font does not yet exist, AFAIK.

The problem does not appear to be linked with the fact that I use a non math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style = TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

\setmathfont{Asana-Math}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}


% {
%   \setmathfont{Asana-Math}

%   \begin{equation}
%     \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
%   \end{equation}
% }


\end{document}
```

However, as @cfr suggested, [I should use `\mathversion`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29509/8425): the following works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style = TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[version=lm]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=asana]{Asana-Math}

\mathversion{lm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

\mathversion{asana}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}

\mathversion{lm}

\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}


{
  \mathversion{asana}

  \begin{equation}
    \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
  \end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you *want* to do this? Why not define another maths version and use that instead?

Comment: @cfr My tcolorbox example environments are in sans serif font. I'd like to have a math font that fits. But I don't know how to do with mathversion. Would you mind writing à code showing how it works with opentype non math fonts?

Comment: Please make sure your code examples compile before posting them unless the error is the problem.

Comment: It would work if you had a suitable sans serif font, but I don't think there are any to be had.

Comment: The problem really is that `unicode-math` is designed to work with opentype maths fonts. It isn't designed to work with other kinds of fonts. While you can persuade it to do some things with them by a combination of brute force and ignorance (in my case, anyway, though probably not yours), there is a real limit to that. `unicode-math` ***needs*** a maths table to work properly. I would suggest simply not using unicode maths fonts if you need to switch to sans serif for maths. Stick to traditional TeX fonts for maths in that case.

Comment: Admittedly, `unicode-math` should not fail quite so confusingly and spectacularly if you try to use `version` here - and I certainly would consider that a bug, even if a satisfactory fix would be to fail with meaningful errors - but it cannot be expected to actually *work*. It just isn't meant to.

Comment: That I know of, there are no sanserif OpenType Math fonts.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your comments (see my edited answer). Would you mind writing an answer so I can grant you the bounty?

Comment: I can't. It isn't just that the fonts you are using are not maths fonts. It doesn't seem to be possible to combine `version` and `range` at all, even if you are trying to restrict the range for a font with a maths table. Perhaps @JosephWright knows if this is a bug or a known limitation and whether there's a workaround.

Comment: @cjorssen See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326876/is-it-possible-to-combine-version-and-range-when-specifying-a-maths-font-with-un.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for asking the right question :) You still deserve the bounty since you clearly identified the true issue here!

Comment: Let's see if you get a proper answer first: your bounty has 5 days to run. No point in wasting it.

Comment: You will probably want to read Ulrike's answer to the question I asked about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really two problems here.

The first is that `unicode-math` really *wants* opentype fonts with a proper `math` table. It only works with fonts lacking this at all, as I understand it, because the configuration falls through to setting the applicable `range` to `up`, despite the font lacking anything which usually enables the setting of ranges etc.

The usual way to set an alternative set of maths fonts is to declare an alternative maths `version` e.g. `bold` versus `normal`. `unicode-math` supports this. This basically works, as your example shows.

However, the second problem is that it seems to be impossible to combine the use of `range` with `version`. Setting a range affects *all* maths versions rather than just the specified one, as I demonstrate in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326876/is-it-possible-to-combine-version-and-range-when-specifying-a-maths-font-with-un).