# Is it possible to combine version and range when specifying a maths font with unicode-math?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode, unicode-math

[Note that I am using LuaTeX for all compilations.]

Consider the following MWE which sets up several versions for maths using `unicode-math`'s `version` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=lm]% sanity check
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=asana]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[version=tgs]
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[version=tgt]
% \setmathfont{Tex Gyre Schola Math}[version=tgs, range=it]
% \setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[version=tgt]
\newcommand*\testmaths{%
\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}
\[
  \sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} = 1
\]
}
\begin{document}
Latin Modern Math (\verb|normal|):
\testmaths

\mathversion{asana}
Asana Math (\verb|asana|):
\testmaths

\mathversion{tgt}
TeX Gyre Termes Math (\verb|tgt|):
\testmaths

\mathversion{normal}
Latin Modern Math (\verb|normal|):
\testmaths

{%
  \mathversion{tgs}
  TeX Gyre Schola Math (\verb|tgs|):
  \testmaths
}

Latin Modern Math (\verb|normal|):
\testmaths

\mathversion{lm}
Latin Modern Math (\verb|lm|):
\testmaths
\end{document}
```

This works fine.

[image: expected output]

However, this code cannot be combined with the use of `range`. Although the effect of `range` is to restrict the specified font to the given range, its use is not then restricted to the specified `version`. Instead, all `version`s are affected.

```
% \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[version=tgs]
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[version=tgt]
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Schola Math}[version=tgs, range=it]
% \setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[version=tgt]
```

[image: all versions affected]

Or, changing the order, the specified range in the specified version simply ends up producing emptiness.

```
% \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[version=tgs]
% \setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[version=tgt]
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Schola Math}[version=tgs, range=it]
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[version=tgt]
```

[image: emptiness]

Why is this and can it be corrected?

## EDIT

It is, of course, true that the above examples are incomplete because they do not define sufficient stuff for an alternative maths version. To do this, additional configuration would be required to ensure that all ranges are set for the alternative maths version(s). However, this cannot be done unless a single font is used for all ranges for a given version. This is quite unlike the standard case, where you must use multiple fonts to ensure complete coverage.

Here's a non-LuaTeX example using various fonts from Arev. The commands are mostly from `arevmath.sty`.  Note that the macros are, essentially, each setting a relevant `range` for the new version, `sansserif`. (Even here, things are not really complete: there are symbols and maths alphabets to worry about. But hopefully the basic idea is clear.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareMathVersion{sansserif}
% modified from arev - node that a complete set up would need additional stuff
\SetSymbolFont{operators}    {sansserif}{OT1}{zavm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}      {sansserif}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}      {sansserif}{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols} {sansserif}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathnormal}{sansserif}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}    {sansserif}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}    {sansserif}{OT1}{zavm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}    {sansserif}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}    {sansserif}{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}    {sansserif}{T1} {fvm} {m}{n}
\newcommand*\testmaths{%
\begin{equation}
  \int_{t = 0}^{x^2} t dt
\end{equation}
\[
  \sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} = 1
\]
}
\begin{document}
Latin Modern Math (\verb|normal|):
\testmaths

\mathversion{sansserif}
Arev (\verb|sansserif|):
\testmaths

\mathversion{normal}
Latin Modern Math (\verb|normal|):
\testmaths
\end{document}
```

[image: non-unicode case]

The question is how to do the equivalent with `unicode-math` if you want `letters` to come from one maths font, say, and `operators` from another.

Comment: This question is the outcome of my attempting first to answer the linked question and then to diagnose the problems I encountered trying to do so. Hence, anybody who answers this one can probably scoop a double bounty from cjorssen ;).

Comment: What you are trying to do is undefined behaviour.  Usually setting `\mathversion` replaces the whole math font.  What should happen when there is a `range` specified?  Should it only display characters from this `range` and undefine all the others?  Should it only apply to characters within `range`? (But then `\mathversion` does not work as expected.  It is to replace the *whole* font.)  I'd say, `\mathversion` is the wrong tool for the job.  What you want (and need) is `\setmathfont`.

Comment: @HenriMenke The example is overly minimal in that respect. That is, of course you would really need to define stuff to ensure that everything is covered by the new version and not just a fraction of it. But it is possible to use different fonts for different bits in standard TeX. (Indeed, it is mandatory.) But there doesn't seem to be a way of doing that here.

Comment: @HenriMenke Please see edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho the answer to the question is "no". Currently it won't work. `unicode-math` implements the range option by defining a new math family and then points the symbol(s) to this family. The code is not "version aware".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$ a $
[class: \Umathcharclass`\a]
[family: \Umathcharfam`\a]
[slot: \Umathcharslot`\a]


\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Schola Math}[range="61]

$ a $
[class: \Umathcharclass`\a]
[family: \Umathcharfam`\a]
[slot: \Umathcharslot`\a]

\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}[range="61]

$ a $
[class: \Umathcharclass`\a]
[family: \Umathcharfam`\a]
[slot: \Umathcharslot`\a]

\end{document}
```

It would be quite difficult to change this -- on the technical side but also regarding the "logic". unicode-math would have to either store long list of symbols which should be remapped to other fonts if the mathversion change, or remap math fonts and in both case it would have to pay attention to varying range blocks in the various math version versions -- a nightmare for a maintainer.

While I do understand that people like to change (or add) glyphs in a math font I think that the `range` option should be used with care and *not* for large scale font manipulations. Imho the future for complicated setups lies not in more unicode-math code but in the "combo" font feature of luaotfload.

Comment: I think you are right. That is, I looked at the code also. (But obviously not knowing as much about it.)

Comment: Thanks Ulrike (+1). Would you mind adding a bit about "combo" font feature and how it could be used here?

Comment: @cjorssen I may be mistaken, but I think that is rather a massive ask under current circumstances. Not only is the code developing fast with scant regard for backwards compatibility, but the documentation is not developing with it, leaving people to effectively try to write the documentation by inferring what various things are intended to do through trial-and-error as much as anything. (Or course, backwards compatibility is not really a consideration, as I understand it, because it is beta software. So this is not necessarily a criticism.)

Comment: @cfr You are probably right. I was asking without knowing anything to those "combo" things.

Comment: @cjorssen There is an example for a combo font here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314397/defining-new-font-family-with-fontspec/314401#314401.