# lualatex chokes on tikzposter + unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, tikzposter, bugs

Using `lualatex`, `LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0` (the most recent version available for my distribution, ArchLinux), the following minimal example never finishes compiling on my machine. It simply stalls at some point, driving my CPU to 100%, so that I have to kill it. Using `xelatex` is a workaround. Is this possibly fixed in more recent versions of `lualatex`?

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

\endinput
```

Comment: it runs without error for me with tl2017 (although not very interesting result)

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour with TL 2016.  However, it is more probable that this used to be an issue with `unicode-math` rather than with LuaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same bug as in [How can I change math font with \setmathfont inside a group?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326521/how-can-i-change-math-font-with-setmathfont-inside-a-group)

The problem is that `tikzposter` wraps the whole document in a group which is done in the hooks `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument`.  Unfortunately, if you do not select a font in the preamble `unicode-math` will try to set the font to Latin Modern Roman when encountering `\begin{document}` which is in a group which makes it hang.

**Workaround:** Explicitly select the fonts in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did find the question you linked, but based on the answers/comments there didn't see the connection to my problem. Thank you for pointing that out!